# Docker Swarm node fails to join after reboot. State 'pending'

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, swarm

I've been able to successfully set up a Docker Swarm cluster with one manager and two worker nodes by running `swarm init` and `swarm join` respectively. `docker node ls` then shows that all nodes are active. However, if one of the worker nodes restarts it won't be able to join back in. Running `docker node ls` on the manager now shows that the newly restarted node is in state `pending`. I've enabled debugging and running `systemctl status docker-latest -l` on the failing-to-join worker node shows lots of these:

`level=error msg="agent: session failed" error="rpc error: code = 13 desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: tls: oversized record received with length 20527\"" module="node/agent"`

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5
Docker version 1.13.1, build 8633870/1.13.1 (installed package `docker-latest` from repository) Also tried the regular docker package with no difference.

Comment: 1.13.1 is a very old and unsupported docker release. Please try upgrading to 18.06.1.